# How can I derive $~\frac{d}{dx}\left(\exp\left(\int f\left(x\right)dx\right)\right)=\exp\left(\int f\left(x\right)dx\right)\cdot f\left(x\right)~$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, exponential-function

$$  P:=\text{function which only contains } ~x~ \text{as variable}  $$

$$  I:= \exp\left(\int P dx\right) $$

I want to derive the below equation .

$$  \frac{  d  }{ dx   } \left( \exp\left(\int P dx\right)  \right) = I \cdot P = \exp\left(\int P dx\right)  \cdot P $$

By the way I assumed that $~ P ~$ can be a constant function of $~ x ~$ . For instance $~ P= 1 ~$  is allowed .

The following info are the things which I know (WIP).

$$  a \in\mathbb{R}  $$

$$ \frac{  d  }{ dx   } \left( \exp\left(ax\right)  \right) = a \cdot \exp\left(a x\right)  $$

Resetted info of $~ a ~$

$$  \frac{  d  }{ dx   }  \left( \int_{a }^{x } f(t) \,dt   \right)  $$

$$ = \frac{  d  }{ dx   }  \left[ F(t) \right]_{a}^{x}  $$

$$ = \frac{  d  }{  dx  } \left\{ F(x)-F(a) \right\}  $$

$$ = \frac{  d  }{ dx   } F(x) -  \underbrace{\frac{  d  }{ dx   } F(a)}_\text{ constant}  $$

$$ = f(x) $$

Comment: Do you know the chain rule? Do you know the derivative of the exponential function? Do you know what the derivative of $\int_a^x f(t) \, dt$ is?

Comment: i will add my info .

Comment: f(x) is the first order derivative of your last given one .

Comment: I know chain rule .

Comment: First recall the following
$$\frac{d}{dx}e^{g(x)}=e^{g(x)} \frac{d}{dx}(g(x))$$
Secondly recall that 
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int h(x)dx=h(x)$$
You are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the chain rule we have

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\exp\left(\int Pdx\right)\right)=\exp\left(\int Pdx\right)\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int Pdx\right)=\exp\left(\int P dx\right)P$$

Answer (score 1):

Apply the chain rule:
$$\dfrac {de^{f(x)}}{dx}=\dfrac {de^{f(x)}}{df(x)}\dfrac {df(x)}{dx}=e^{f(x)}f'(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dx} e^{2x} = 2e^{2x}$$

how do you do this? It's the same thing...well assuming by '$\int f(x) dx$' you mean $F=F(x)$ as any antiderivative of $f=f(x)$ (where FTC tells us integral = antiderivative. or just ignore this part if $\int$ means just antiderivative instead of integral).

But maybe there's some uniqueness of derivative of antiderivative issue here? idk. $F$ and $G$ are antiderivatives of $f$ iff they differ by a constant....sooooo yeah....

well I assume '$\int f(x) dx$' refers to the same antiderivative on both LHS and RHS. i mean we obviously can't have

$$\frac{d}{dx} e^{2x+7} = 2e^{2x+28.99\pi}$$